# Improve code with NEON on iOS - use VCEQ then VBIT

Tags: ios, arm, neon

I am writing a histogram like function which looks at vector data and then puts the elements in predefined "histogram" buckets based on which range they are closest to.

I can obviously do this using if condition but I am trying to improve it using NEON because these are image buffers.

One way to do this would be with  VCEQ then VBIT but sadly enough I could not find VBIT in the header of neon. Alternatively I figured I could take the VCEQ results and do an exclusive AND with a vector of 1s and then use VBIF :-) but VBIF is not there either!

Any thoughts here?
Thanks

Comment: Is it possible for you to share a pseudo algorithm on how you do this?

Comment: @auselen, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926351/c-versus-vdsp-versus-neon-how-could-neon-be-as-slow-as-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VBIT`, `VBIF`, and `VBSL` all do the same operation up to permutation of the sources; you can use the `vbsl*` intrinsics to get any of the three operations.

Comment: Stephen: if you can look at the follow up question, it would be much appreciated:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926351/c-versus-vdsp-versus-neon-how-could-neon-be-as-slow-as-c#comment20944212_14926351